# Tortoise SVN - Update Specific Folders only?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm not too sure how to word this because I've not got any idea on the technical names for things.

**Essentially I have a folder tree?:**

Like this - Probably incorrect format, but as an idea:

[image]

*There are several more folders inside each month, all with their own individual folders.

**If I wanted to updated a specific branch?, for example:**

*Images > 2014 > October > 06 > Updates > 01*

Without updating the whole repository, how would I do that?

Thanks!!

I'm not sure I used tree and branch in the correct way, so sorry if I have offended you! :)

Comment: You would just right click on the specific folder and do an update. You don't need to do an update on just the parent to update children.

Comment: Hi @Aibrean .  I forgot to mention, I don't have anything downloaded yet.  All I have is my base "images" folder.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! If you want to post that as an answer it's yours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just right click on the specific folder and do an update. You don't need to do an update on just the parent to update children.

You can do a selective checkout too.

Comment: How do I use the svn command from a script to update a only specific folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57514923/3739498 - specific folder casd