# Git push to specific folder on remote repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, directory, push

How can I push to specific folder in the remote repository? I have the following structure on my local C drive:

```
myfolder/
    .git
    folder1
    folder2
    folder3
    folder4
    .gitignore
```

I executed `git init` command in this folder. After that I did `git add .` and then `git commit -m "My first commit"` Now I would like to push it to the VSTS **remote** repository that contains similar structure:

> https://helloworld.visualstudio.com/VSTS_folder/_git/VSTS_folder

```
VSTS_folder/
   greenFolder
   redFolder
   blueFolder
   blackFolder
   yellowFolder
   .gitignore
   README.md
```

where **VSTS_folder** is the name of the repository. *greenFolder*, *redFolder* and *yellowFolder* have some code in there already. What I would like to do is to push my local stuff to *blackFolder* remote folder which is empty. I'm trying to avoid messing with the repo and pushing my stuff to the root. I was using `git remote add origin https://helloworld.visualstudio.com/VSTS_folder/_git/VSTS_folder/blackFolder` but that didn't work. What's the appropriate git command for achieving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not how Git works. You have one **repository** called `VSTS_folder`. Whoever created that repo didn't understand what a Git repository is.

You need to *clone* the repository, which will give you a copy of the entire repo. Then you can add additional code to it.

If all of these folders contain totally independent projects that share nothing between them, then you should consider splitting them into separate repos.

You would also hugely benefit for sitting down and reading a Git tutorial to get a better understanding of these concepts.

Comment: I have iOS project and when I am pushing my code it is saying repo size exceeds 100mb. Now I added pods in gitignore still getting same message. Can you please suggest how can I push my complete code

Comment: @Chandni That is a totally unrelated question. If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

For Git version control system, it push changes to remote repo by **branches** (not by folders as svn VCS).

So you need to **move the local stuff into `blackFolder`, and pull changes from remote repo (VSTS git repo), and finally push the branch into VSTS git repo**.

Detail steps as below:

```
# In your local git repo
rm -Rf .git #it's uncessary to commit at first in your local repo
git init
git remote add origin https://helloworld.visualstudio.com/VSTS_folder/_git/VSTS_folder -f
mkdir blackFolder
mv * blackFolder
mv .gitignore blackFolder
git pull origin master
git add .
git commit -m 'add local stuff to remote repo blackFolder'
git push -u origin master
```

Now the local stuff are push to the VSTS git repo under `blackFolder`.

Comment: these make a local blackfolder "mkdir blackFolder
mv * blackFolder
mv .gitignore blackFolder"  

what i dont get is why the need to "git pull origin master"?

Answer (score 3):

```
git add .\<folder name>
git push
```

That should be all you need. I just did it