# Using Git push from local to a child folder in Remote Repository (Not the root) - GitLab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

In my remote repository I have a branch called 'MyProject'
and have three sub folders :

MyProject (Root)

Folder1 : Code

Folder2 : Documents

Folder3 : Notes

I use the following command to push

```
git init
git add.
git remote add origin myUrl
git push -u origin  MyProject
```

However, all the files are pushed to the Root -> 'MyProject', while I need to push them to the 'Code' subfolder.

I've looked at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338700/git-push-to-specific-folder-on-remote-repository) but it doesn't give me a good insight to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a remote repository use `git clone myUrl` instead of `git init` and `git remote add`. You should then have the desired folder structure on your local host. Copy your contents to the code folder and add / commit / push them.

Possible duplicate of: [Checkout subdirectories in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180052/checkout-subdirectories-in-git)